# Dataframe groups in two independent t test and view like spps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As shown in the picture, I want to compare the variable gm1 for the dimension A with the period 201802 to 201803 and 201804, and then I would like to compare the period of 201803 with the period 201802 and 201804. In the second step, I like to add statistical representation like A, B and so on.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

How is your source data organized?  I am assuming the table you put together is built from the raw data.  It may be easier to go from the raw data to a pandas dataframe, then run analysis on that dataframe to get the stats you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I have the source data. However, my problem is to provide a generalized loop in this structure and to perform the analysis by sending the mean standard deviation and sample number as a parameter.

Comment: Can you give an example of how that source data is structured?  I think it'll be easier to go from the source data than from the table you created in the attached image.